# Import Class of a similar package

Tags: java, eclipse, package, structure

I'm now in a new project. There is the following folder structure:

```
* fsaapp-business
  - com.fsa.fsaapp.business.monitor
    > JenkinsStatBusinessService.java
```

---

```
* fsaapp-business-impl
  - com.fsa.fsaapp.business.stat
    > StatistikViewModel.java
```

---

```
* --> Project
- --> Package
> --> Class / Interface
```

Now I have this Interface:
**JenkinsStatBusinessService.java**

```
package com.fsa.fsaapp.business.monitor;

import com.fsa.fsaapp.business.stat.StatistikViewModel;


public interface JenkinsStatBusinessService {

    public String collectStatistics();

    public String getDurchschnittBisLetzterTag();

    public StatistikViewModel getBuildCounts();

}
```

Now the import of `StatistikViewModel` gives me this error:

```
The import com.fsa.fsaapp.business.stat cannot be resolved
```

I think this is because this Interface search `*.stat` in the `fsaapp-business` project, and not in the `fsaapp-business-impl` project.

So how can I import the `StatistikViewModel` out of the `impl` into the `business`?

Comment: Is `StatistikViewModel` a class? Have you used two projects for separating api from impl?

Comment: Is this a typo in your question or those are the actual class names? "> Stat **sit** ikViewModel.java", "Stat **ist** ikViewModel"

Comment: @RohitJain: Yes `StatistikViewModel` is a class. I don't know exactly why it get seperated. I only know that in the not-impl project are many `Interfaces`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the `fsaapp-business-impl` project and select *Properties*. In the *Project References* tab, select your other project and click OK.

This will ensure your other project is on the library path and should allow you to resolve classes from that project.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
import com.fsa.fsaapp.business.stat.*;
```

this must do the job..